# GridSearchCV with LGBMRegressor can't find best parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, lightgbm

I have 2 regressors:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

params = {
    'num_leaves': [7, 14, 21, 28, 31, 50],
    'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.03, 0.003],
    'max_depth': [-1, 3, 5],
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200, 500],
}

grid = GridSearchCV(lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=0), params, scoring='r2', cv=5)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

reg = lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=0)
```

As you see, I defined a `random_state` for both regressors. `GridSearchCV` must find the best params for estimator to increace its `scroring`. But

```py
r2_score(y_train, grid.predict(X_train)) # output is 0.69
r2_score(y_train, reg.predict(X_train))  # output is 0.84
```

So, how can find best params for `LGBMRegressor`?

Comment: I guess this is a conceptual issue. You are training and predicting using the same dataset. I'd say you have a biased classifier, and the cross validation acts to smooth this bias.

Comment: The R2 is pretty high. Why could be the bias?

Comment: Any model evaluation should be carried in a different set from the one used for training. Here you find an interesting discussion about it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/why-not-validate-on-the-entire-training-set

Comment: I didn't tried to evaluate the model. `GridSeachCV` is supposed to find best parameters for the highest score. And it didn't find them. That's the problem

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) here, after calling `grid.fit()` you can find the best estimator (ready model) and params here:

```
grid.best_estimator_
grid.best_params_
```

FYI: `random_state` works just for random cases (when shuffling for example).
In your case the params for models are different and the results of your metric R2 are accordingly different.

Answer (score 2):

So, I believe you would have to script it like:

```
params = {
    'num_leaves': [7, 14, 21, 28, 31, 50],
    'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.03, 0.003],
    'max_depth': [-1, 3, 5],
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200, 500],
}

grid = GridSearchCV(lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=0), params, scoring='r2', cv=5)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

reg = lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=0)
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

lgbm_tuned = grid.best_estimator_

r2_tuned = grid.best_params_
r2_regular = r2_score(y_train, reg.predict(X_train))
```

when r2_tuned is the best score found with Grid Search, lgbm_tuned is your model defined with the best parameters and r2_regular is your score with default parameters.

It is weird to find a worst result after gridsearch, specially when the parameters for the gridsearch includes the default parameters for LightGBM.